# bootstrap modal fades in, but the container remains empty

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I want to include a simple bootstrap modal. The code is minimal, but there seems to be something wrong.

When I click the "Launch demo" button, the modal fades in, but the container that should hold the ".modal-header" ".modal-body" and ".modal-footer" is empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">     
    </head>
    <body>               
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
            <div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
                    <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                    <h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
                    <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
            <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
        </div> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your markup for the modal box wasn't correct.
Basically change it to this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">     
    </head>
    <body>               
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>  
            <div id="example" class="modal fade" style="display: none; "> 
     <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">   
     <div class="modal-header">  
     <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>  
     <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>  
     </div>  
     <div class="modal-body">  
     <h4>Text in a modal</h4>  
     <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
     </div>  
     <div class="modal-footer">  
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
     <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
     </div>
    </div>     
    </div>
            </div>  
            <p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a></p>  
        </div> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Note:

- #example hade a class 'hide' which wasn't changed after clicking the button
- inside #example there where missing modal-dialog and modal-content box
- I changed the jQuery pull from cdn to version 1.11.2 instead of 1.11.1.

Hope this helps.